# 'file.existsSync()': is not true

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I am going to store an image in firebase storage. When I send file through image picker then its working fine. But when I manually pass link of image then it is showing an error that says:

```
'package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart': 
Failed assertion: line 62 pos 12: 'file.existsSync()': is not true.
```

I am writing following code:

```
File image =  File("assets/img/pic.jpg");

final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('image');

InkWell(
            child: Text("Tap to Upload"),
            onTap: () {
              firebaseStorageRef.putFile(image);
            },
          ),
```

Comment: You can't use `File` with assets as they aren't real files. If you want to upload an asset, load the asset into memory using `RootBundle` then use `putData` instead of `putFile`.

Answer (score 9):

The error says it, the file doesn't exists, before doing that you should check if the file is there or create it if it's not

```
InkWell(
   child: Text("Tap to Upload"),
   onTap: () async {
     File image = await File("assets/img/pic.jpg").create(); 
     // it creates the file,
     // if it already existed then just return it
     // or run this if the file is created before the onTap
     // if(image.existsSync()) image = await image.create();
     firebaseStorageRef.putFile(image);
   },
),
```

Also I'm not sure if you can change/create files in the assets folder, if that doesn't work maybe try to put the file in a temp directory of your app

Answer (score 3):

The Assets in Flutter are not directly accessible as File objects. To upload an image from the assets folder to Firebase Storage, you have to upload it to memory first using RootBundle, you can use the putData method instead of putFile.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
final imageBytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/img/pic.jpg');
final imageData = imageBytes.buffer.asUint8List();

final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('image');

InkWell(
    child: Text("Tap to Upload"),
    onTap: () {
        firebaseStorageRef.putData(imageData);
            },
       ),
```